# Removing CSS class from <li> tag in ASP.net from code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, css

I add a css class to my li tag like following:

```
liComPapers.Attributes.Add("class", "NoDisplay");
```

Is there any way to remove this specific class (NoDisplay) from that li tag somewhere else in my code?

I have tried the following code but it is not working.

```
liComPapers.Attributes["class"] = "";
```

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've just made a sample to test your code, and found that the following part will do exactly what you want:

```
 var newClassValue = liTest.Attributes["class"].Replace("NoDisplay", "");
 liTest.Attributes["class"] = newClassValue;
```

**Tested and Working:** 
if (for some reason) the above code didn't work, I would recommend another approach, which is similar to the previous, with another way to replace the class value

```
var newClassValue = liTest.Attributes["class"].Replace("NoDisplay", "");
liTest.Attributes.Remove("class");
liTest.Attributes.Add("class",newClassValue);
```

Answer (score 7):

If I understand correctly:

If you wish to remove only `NoDisplay`, you could replace that part of the string with an empty string:

```
liComPapers.Attributes["class"] = liComPapers.Attributes["class"].Replace("NoDisplay", "");
```

---

However, `.Add("class", "NoDisplay")` won't add a new class to your class attribute. It will create a new `class` attribute with the value `NoDisplay`. Therefore if your markup is currently:

```
<li class="myClass"></li>
```

It would become:

```
<li class="myClass" class="NoDisplay"></li>
```

This is invalid markup.

To append new classes to an element with existing classes, you can do:

```
liComPapers.Attributes["class"] += " NoDisplay";
```

This would then render:

```
<li class="myClass NoDisplay"></li>
```

Comment: you gt it slightly faster than me :)

Answer (score 2):

```
liComPapers.Attributes.Remove("class");
```

we can  remove the CSS attribute for the Particular li tag

Answer (score 2):

Suggested method

```
liComPapers.Attributes["class"] = liComPapers.Attributes["class"].Replace("NoDisplay", "");
```

will cut another css classes that contains string `"NoDisplay"` and will cause errors

E.g.

```
<li class="NoDisplay AnotherClass-NoDisplay"></li>
```

becomes

```
<li class=" AnotherClass-"></li>
```

---

So, more safely solution would be

```
liComPapers.Attributes["class"] = String.Join(" ", liComPapers.Attributes["class"]
                                        .Split(' ')
                                        .Where(x => x != "NoDisplay")
                                        .ToArray());
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
liComPapers.Attributes.Remove("class");
```

[AttributeCollection.Remove Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.attributecollection.remove.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems right.
Check this link: [How to: Set HTML Attributes for Controls in ASP.NET Web Pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7a9d6h4f%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Are you using callbacks/ajax? Maybe you are not considering that..

Try to do a simple page with only one control and put a button to do a postback , on the button's click event (server side) assign the attribute the same way you did before. It should works.